# Traefik not routing to other containers

Tags: wordpress, docker, traefik

I've set up Traefik and Portainer on my server running Ubuntu 20.04 that is in my front room (I used this guide and this one, but didn't set up the default IP whitelist in the second tutorial as I want it to be a publicly accessible webserver). Both apps work and appear to be using HTTPS. I can manage and create containers in Portainer.

To test out my configuration, I added two containers - MySQL and Wordpress. I added in the Traefik labels from the above tutorials like when I set up Traefik, and I set the Wordpress container's domain name in Portainer, but whenever I try to access the Wordpress site at that domain, I get a Bad Gateway error (just the words 'Bad Gateway', not even a status code).

I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Here are my configuration files:

traefik.yml:

```
api:
  dashboard: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    filename: /config.yml
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./data/acme.json:/acme.json
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.mywebsite.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=michael:$$apr1$$.m1mfSB0$$6Ypx6rfih8y.vHkNQe9rJ0"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik.mywebsite.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
certificatesResolvers:
  http:
    acme:
      email: me@myemail.com
      storage: acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: http
```

config.yml:

```
http:
  middlewares:
    https-redirect:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./data/acme.json:/acme.json
      - ./data/config.yml:/config.yml:ro
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.mywebsite.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=michael:$$apr1$$.m1mfSB0$$6Ypx6rfih8y.vHkNQe9rJ0"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik.mywebsite.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

Wordpress/MySQL docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: admin
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpressdb
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - proxy
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress.rule=Host(`myblog.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress.middlewares=https-redirect@file"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress-secure.rule=Host(`myblog.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wordpress-secure.service=wordpress"
      - "traefik.http.services.wordpress.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: username
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - proxy
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mysql.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mysql.middlewares=https-redirect@file"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mysql-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mysql-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mysql-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mysql-secure.service=mysql"
      - "traefik.http.services.mysql.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"

volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

I can provide the Portainer docker-compose.yml file too if needed, but I don't really think it's necessary. Any help here would be great!

Comment: Any news on this one?

Answer (score 1):

For network connectivity between the different applications you must create the network in one of your applications. I would do that in your traefik docker-compose.yml

Meaning, that in your traefik compose file you must NOT specify the proxy network as external, because you create it internally in that application like this:

```
networks:
  proxy:
```

In your Wordpress/MySQL docker-compose.yml you must specify a name for the external network like this:

```
networks:
  proxy:
    external:
      name: "traefik_proxy"
```

When you create a new application using compose, everything in the application gets a prefix, that is the directoryname in which the compose file is placed.

Meaning the above example only works if your traefik compose file is placed in a directory named "traefik"

This should fix your issue with connectivity.